# error in inserting of form data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have created a register form but whenever I try to insert data to database it dont give me error rather it stays on the same page with the filled data.I have created this in codeigniter.Below is my code.

**Controller File: Home.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->library(array('session','form_validation','email'));
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('Sign');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home/index');
    }



    function signup()
    {
        $occu = $this->input->post('occupation');
        $cf = $this->input->post('codefest');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','Name','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile','Mobile No','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpass','Cofirm Password','trim|required|matches[password]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('occupation','Occupation','trim|required|callback_select_validate');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('institute','Institute Name','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('company','Company Name','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('codefest','Codefest','trim|required|callback_select_codefest');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('address1','Address','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pincode','Pincode','trim|required');


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            // fails
            $this->load->view('home/index');
        }
        else
            {
            //echo "inserted";
            $data = array
            ('user_name' => $this->input->post('fname'),
             'mobile_no' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
             'user_email' => $this->input->post('email'),
             'user_password' => $this->input->post('cpass'),
             'occupation' => $this->input->post('occupation'),
             'institute_name' => $this->input->post('institute'),
             'company_name' => $this->input->post('company'),
             'codefest_city' => $this->input->post('codefest'),
             'address' => $this->input->post('address1'),
             'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
             'pincode' => $this->input->post('pincode'));  

            // insert form data into database
            if ($this->Sign->insertUser($data))
            {

                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your Message has been successfully received.We will back to you soon.</div>');
                    redirect('home/index');
            }
            else
                {
                    // error
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                    redirect('home/index');
                } 
            }




    }

    // Below function is called for validating select option field.
    function select_validate($occu)
    {
    if($occu=="none"){
    $this->form_validation->set_message('select_validate', 'Please Select Your Occupation.');
    return false;
    } else{
// User picked something.
    return true;
    }
}

    function select_codefest($cf)
    {
    if($cf=="none"){
    $this->form_validation->set_message('select_codefest', 'Please Select a Codefest.');
    return false;
    } else{
// User picked something.
    return true;
    }
}

}

/* End of file Home.php */
/* Location: .//C/Users/CYBERBUFF/AppData/Local/Temp/fz3temp-1/Home.php */
```

**Model File: Sign.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Sign extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function insertUsers($data)
    {
        return $this->db->insert('signup',$data);
    }

}

/* End of file Sign.php */
/* Location: .//C/Users/CYBERBUFF/AppData/Local/Temp/fz3temp-1/Sign.php */
```

**View File : index.php**

```
<div class="second-col col-md-6 col-sm-3">
  <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>

        <div class="contact-area-left">

         <h4>Sign Up</h4>

         <?php echo form_open('home/signup', array('class' =>'comments-form contact-form'));?>
         <div class="row" align="center">
         <div class="form-group col-lg-10">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="Full Name" value="<?php echo set_value('fname');?>">
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('fname'); ?></span>
          </div> 
          <div class="form-group col-lg-10">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" placeholder="Your Mobile No" value="<?php echo set_value('mobile');?>">
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('mobile'); ?></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-lg-10">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" value="<?php echo set_value('email');?>">
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-lg-5">                        
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="<?php echo set_value('password');?>">
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-lg-5">                        
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" value="<?php echo set_value('cpass');?>">
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('cpass'); ?></span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-lg-10">                        
        <select  class="form-control" name="occupation" id="occupation" onchange="CheckContact(this.value);"  >
        <option value="none" selected="selected">------------Select Occupation------------</option>
        <option value="student">Student</option>
        <option value="professional">Professional</option>
        </select>
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('occupation'); ?></span>
          </div>  

          <div class="form-group col-lg-10" id="student" style="display: none;">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="institute" placeholder="Institute Name" value="<?php echo set_value('institute');?>">
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('institute'); ?></span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-lg-10" id="professional" style="display: none;">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" placeholder="Company Name" value="<?php echo set_value('company');?>">
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('company'); ?></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-lg-10">                        
        <select  class="form-control" name="codefest">
        <option value="none" selected="selected">------------Select Codefest------------</option>
        <option value="cf_ agartala">Codefest Agartala</option>
        <option value="cf_bhubaneswar">Codefest Bhubaneswar</option>
        <option value="cf_chennai">Codefest Chennai</option>
        <option value="cf_guwahati">Codefest Guwahati</option>
        <option value="cf_kolkata">Codefest Kolkata</option>
        </select>
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('codefest'); ?></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-lg-10">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address1" placeholder="Address" value="<?php echo set_value('address1');?>">
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('address1'); ?></span>
          </div>
          <!--<div class="form-group col-lg-5">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address2" placeholder="Address Line 2 (optional)" value="<?php echo set_value('address2');?>">
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('address2'); ?></span>
          </div>-->

          <div class="form-group col-lg-5">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="City" value="<?php echo set_value('city');?>">
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('city'); ?></span>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-lg-5">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pincode" placeholder="PIN Code" value="<?php echo set_value('pincode');?>">
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('pincode'); ?></span>
          </div>
</div>


          <div class="row" align="center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Reset</button>
        </div>

                    <?php echo form_close(); ?> 

   </div>
```

Comment: first of all the spelling of model name you are calling is wrong.

Comment: Then what it would be?

Comment: your model name is  insertUsers and you are calling  insertUser in the controller..

Comment: again not working.

Comment: Try to set model name is `Sign_model` and then call in Controller: `$this->Sign_model->insertUser($data)`

Answer (score 1):

These required fields are hidden in form so validation fails;

```
         <div class="form-group col-lg-10" id="student" style="display: none;">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="institute" placeholder="Institute Name" value="<?php echo set_value('institute');?>">
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('institute'); ?></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-lg-10" id="professional" style="display: none;">                        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" placeholder="Company Name" value="<?php echo set_value('company');?>">
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('company'); ?></span>
          </div>
```

but validations are in controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('institute','Institute Name','trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('company','Company Name','trim|required');
```

remove the validation if not needed. :)